# No LAN Adapter | LAN Miniport missing from adapters

Tags: networking, windows-10, drivers, lan

I've just bought a Acer Aspire E5-575G (not the best choice for gaming, but on a budget). I've been happily using it for playing games and browsing the net, but I turned it on again a month after having it to see the "Network Connections" icon turn from LAN to Wireless.

The last connection I had plugged into it was a **LAN cable which worked perfectly fine** and dandy. I went to "Change network adapter settings" thinking I could change it back to my wired internet to find there was no Ethernet adapter, but just the Atheros Wireless adapter (in this laptop, it's only 72MB/s)

I then restarted my laptop thinking the adapter hasn't started correctly. When I restarted, the "Network Connections" icons briefly flashed the LAN icon with the "No connections X" over it then changed to wireless. Still, no Ethernet adapter was available to select. I then went to Device manager and saw that there was no LAN drivers installed, just Atheros and the standard WAN IP and WAN IPv6 drivers.
I then perused the Acer Driver site and found the only available LAN driver for my model of laptop, Realtek. I downloaded a fresh copy of this driver and installed it and got, from what I've looked up, the "Deep sleep" error. I configured my power settings to never sleep or turn off when plugged in, restarted and tried again and got the same error. To add to this, when the LAN driver was working, I never remember it saying "Realtek" anything, but I could be wrong.

Related pages I've looked at:

- [LAN Adapter not present in Windows 7. What can I do to fix it?](https://superuser.com/questions/1010195/lan-adapter-not-present)
- [LAN adapter vanishes occasionally on HP notebook](https://superuser.com/questions/308775/lan-adapter-vanishes-occasionally-on-hp-notebook)
- ["Missing" Realtek 8111E adapter on Gigabyte GA-P67A-UD4-B3](https://superuser.com/questions/329798/missing-realtek-8111e-adapter-on-gigabyte-ga-p67a-ud4-b3)

[image: Acer website]

Comment: 72MB/s is terrible? What kind of Internet connection do you have? Gigabit fiber?

Comment: Gigabit, but not fiber unfortunately.

Comment: use latest driver from Realtek: http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false

Comment: used the latest driver and got the same deep sleep error.

Comment: boot linux live dvd and look if it shows up there. if not the nic chip is damaged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing a problem of a hardware device disappearing from a computer whose software configuration didn't as much as change. Furthermore, your Device Manager is not even reporting the existence of the device, as opposed to slapping a warning symbol on it.  Hence, the only logical outcome is a hardware failure.

If there is warranty period left on your laptop, you must quickly take it to a repair center.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove all battery source  -- unplug, remove battery (if built in, you have to disconnect battery cable from board) 
-- w8 w8 w8 ..  .. .. not more than 1 minute

plug it back, power on your computer, check your eth lan

hope it work, my problem is fixed.

Comment: Yep tried that with the built-in battery. nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

As Fleet Command said, I most likely have a hardware malfunction on this laptop. I ended up purchasing an external Ethernet adapter which is actually better considering its a normal RJ45 connector with WAG light indicators, unlike the "modern" but stupid one on the PC that's engineered to break in days.

Comment: You might want to throw fleet command at least an upvote, or even select his as the correct answer in this case. I do consider this an *answer* but it would be nice to close the loop on the question.